# ADFS multiple relying party and claim rules to fall back between them

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, adfs, adfs3.0

1) I've an Active Directory, that knows 100% users and IdP that knows let's say 50% of them. I would like ADFS first check if user exists in IdP(RP0) and based on response (Authorized, Not Authorized, Doesn't exist) will query LDAP(RP1) (Active directory), if user doesn't exist in IdP.

Is it possible? And what should be the claim rules to achieve that?

2) Is it possible to implement plugin for ADFS that can help achieve [1]? Is this ADFS API valid for latest ADFS version?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb625463(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I would create an explicit federation so that users are presented with a HRD page where they select how they want to authenticate, ADFS or the other IdP. Doing anything in the background (in your case - asking the other IdP actively) usually breaks sooner or later, in your case it would break when the other IdP federates with yet another IdP or introduces a two factor auth, for example.

Comment: I'm looking from a Dev point of view. Goal is to intercept authentication and validate it before hand off to ADFS claims logic.

Comment: I know, years ago I wrote a 6 part tutorial on that http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/09/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-in-web_2465.html but today I would not recommend this approach for reasons I mentioned. Explicit passive scenario would work always, as long as you go active, changes are the solution is temporary.

Answer (score 1):

No - you can't do this with claims rules.

ADFS can only authenticate against AD, not against LDAP.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response! What do you think about this. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823754.aspx Seems like I can implement my own authentication store that can go both IdP and AD?

Comment: Note the sentence "Applies To: Windows Server Technical Preview". It's for ADFS 4.0 - Server 2016.